# Why is my controller so slow?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm on an app that retrieve datas (a 7k lines CSV formated string) from an external server to update my own entity. Each row is an item in a stock.

Today the job is nicely done but it's very very very slow: more than 60s (prod env) to retrieve datas, push it in a 2D array, update the BDD, and finally load a page that display the bdd content.
When only displaying the page it's about 20s (still prod).

This the profiler's timeline result while only displaying records : [Symfony's profiler timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPMF3.png)
Anymore, i'm not able to profile the "updateAction" cause i't don't appear in the last ten request list.

2 days ago I was checking each row of the CSV file to add it only if needed, I was soft-deleting items to restore it later when back in the stock etc. but with that speed I tried many things to have normal performances.
At the begening everything was in the controler, I moved the function that add/remove in a dedicated service, then in the repository to finally get it back in my controler. To have decent results I tried to empty the database and then refill it without checking. First, using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE but it is not compatible with my table pattern (or I mis understood something) and now I'm simply emptying the table before filling it with the CSV (without any control). The time score I gave earlier was with this last try (which is the best one).
But enought talk
here is my controler:

```
public function majMatosClanAction()
{
    $resMaj = $this->majClanCavernes();
    if ($resMaj === NULL) 
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('alert-danger', 'Unidentified');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('loki_gbl'));
    } else if ($resMaj === FALSE)
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('alert-warning','password update required');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('loki_gbl_ST'));
    } else
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('alert-success','success');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('loki_gbl_voirMatosClan'));
    }
}
```

here is the function that my controller call:

```
public function majClanCavernes()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $outils = $this->container->get('loki_gbl.outils');

    if ($user !== NULL) 
    {
        $pwd = $user->getGob()->getPwd();
        $num = $user->getGob()->getNum();
        if($outils->checkPwd($num, $pwd) !== TRUE) return FALSE;

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //This is a temporary solution
//////////////////////////////////////////////
        $connection = $em->getConnection();
        $platform   = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
        $connection->executeUpdate($platform->getTruncateTableSQL('MatosClan', true ));
//////////////////////////////////////////////

        $repository = $em->getRepository('LokiGblBundle:MatosClan');

        $urlMatosClan = "http://ie.gobland.fr/IE_ClanCavernes.php?id=".$num."&passwd=".$pwd;
        //encode and format the string via a service
        $infosBrutes = $outils->fileGetInfosBrutes($urlMatosClan);
        //$csv is a 2D array containing the datas
        $csv = $outils->getDatasFromCsv($infosBrutes);

        foreach($csv as $item)
        {
            $newItem = new MatosClan;                   
            $newItem->setNum($item[0]);
            $newItem->setType($item[1]);
            [...]
            $em->persist($newItem);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

What is wrong? 7k lines is not that big!

Could it be a lack of [hardware](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/products/DS216j#spec) issue?

Comment: so which part of the code is slow? You have profiled it, haven't you?

Comment: I did, however only the viewAction can be found in the profiler. can't find the updateAction, even in the "last 10 results". I edited my message and added the timeline symfony' profiler is giving me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out doctrine's batch processing documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing).

You can also disable logging:

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

Comment: I disabled logging but it has no real effetcs only 2s. And batch processing is not helping either when I want to add each row. And I don't see how it could help displaying faster.

Comment: This time I earned 10s (with a batchSize = 100, no change with 1000 and 2s with 20). More and more, i think it's a hardware issue. I'm going to try to move my app on a serious hosting solution. Thx for the time you took to answer

Comment: More ram will do the truck for now. Best of luck.